# How can I assign each item in a list a seperate number, and then print these numbers as a string? - Python

Tags: python, string, list, enumerate

please bear with me as I'm rather new to python.

I would like to take a string of a few words, change this to a list, and give each item in the list an individual number (i guess you call it an index). I've looked around for solutions and seen the enumerate function mentioned often. I am able to use it, but what i would like to do is assign the duplicate words in the string the same index as the one before it. I have no clue how to accomplish this!

For example, if the sample inout string is:

```
"How does one do this How does one do this"
```

The sample output string should be:

```
"1234512345"
```

*Explanation:* the word "How" is assigned 1, and "does" 2 etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hey look, you started on how to code! Great. Take what you told us, put it into comment blocks using `#` in front of the line, and start coding what you told us. You want something how would you go about doing it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: Sorry, I will remember this for future use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the sample code. Value of each variable is mentioned in comment at each step to explain you regarding how it worked:

```
my_string = "How does one do this How does one do this"

my_list = my_string.split(" ")
# my_list: ['How', 'does', 'one', 'do', 'this', 'How', 'does', 'one', 'do', 'this']

count = 1
my_dict = {}
for item in my_list:
    if item not in my_dict:
        my_dict[item] = count
        count += 1
# my_dict: {'this': 5, 'How': 1, 'does': 2, 'do': 4, 'one': 3}

num_list = [str(my_dict[item]) for item in my_list]
# num_list: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

num_string = ''.join(num_list)
# num_string: '1234512345'
```

*Alternatively,* if you need **one line solution**, you may use `list.index()` to achieve it. Below is the equivalent code:

```
num_string = ''.join([str(my_list.index(item)+1) for item in my_list])
# num_string: '1234512345'
```

where `my_list` is holding the value from my above example.

Comment: Thank you, this works very well!

Answer (score 1):

Tokenize the string, then associate a number every time a new word is found.

```
string1 = 'How does one do this How does one do this'
tokens = string1.split()
d = {}

count=1

rval=[]
for t in tokens:
    if t in d:
        # token has a reference in dictionary, append it to the list, as string
        rval.append(str(d[t]))
    else:
        # create a new reference and append it to the list
        d[t] = count
        rval.append(str(count))
        count+=1


print("".join(rval))
```

result

```
1234512345
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works a treat!